# Meta Stack Overflow reports a reputation for Stack Overflow that is different from the reputation reported from Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I just noticed a strange situation; maybe it is a bug or can be explained some other way.

This is a screenshot of what I see; the top part is from Stack Overflow, and the bottom one from Meta Stack Overflow. I figured they should probably show the same values.

[image: screenshot]

**Update**

Well, it has been 24 hours now and the reputation matches but I think this is probably just a coincidence since I happened to get a couple of up votes this morning on SO.  The badges are still showing as different (the second badge on MSO was earned about 8 days ago now surely that is very old for a cache isn't it?).

**Second Update**

So when I updated this message I got the editor badge which made my badge total on MSO 3 and so now both sites agree.

Comment: I think that is cached

Comment: browser cache?  I tried ctrl+f5 on both pages and they still disagree (I also closed the browser entirely and re-opened it)

Comment: No, cached on the servers itself.

Comment: @Benny I thought so too at first, but then noticed that the discrepancy in rep was not due to recently lost rep (actual SO rep lower than stated on MSO page). Unless the drop is due to a recent recalc or vote-fraud adjustments?

Comment: Also noted that the last badge he/she earned on MSO was a good 7 days ago. That's a rather stale loaf were it cached data.

Comment: @Benny the cache issue is on other metas. MSO has separate rep from SO.

Comment: @Shawn also? Se my answer below.

Comment: This problem appears to be no longer reproducible after Meta Stack Overflow was renamed to Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow was given a proper child meta.

Answer (score 1):

From your reputation changes at StackOverflow, I can see that your reputation has changed +5 just yesterday. This happened with me too when I signed up at [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com). After a day, I checked and it was updated. So my advice (Just an advice) is wait for at least 24 hours for your reputation to propagate to all the sites in StackExchange network because  there is probably some caching mechanism across SE network.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I am sure the rep thing will probably sort itself out but I wonder about the badge - I earned the badge on meta 7 days ago and it hasn't made it to the overview screen on stack overflow yet - that seems a bit of a long time doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, I suspected this might indeed be a bug. However, this is no longer an issue since the [site specific "accounts" tab has now been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128245/accounts-tab-has-been-removed-but-the-section-title-on-the-summary-page-still-li) in favour of a [centralised StackExchange version](https://stackexchange.com/users/1031737/user1039947?tab=accounts).

These changes are currently in progress<sup>**ŧ**</sup> and we can expect to see a more intuitive link on the profile pages to lead you to that page.

<sub>**ŧ** See: [Accounts tab has been removed but the section title on the summary page still links to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128245/accounts-tab-has-been-removed-but-the-section-title-on-the-summary-page-still-li/128268#128268)</sub>