# Accounts tab has been removed but the section title on the summary page still links to it

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, summary

I see that the Accounts tab has been removed from our Profile pages now:

[image: No Accounts tab]

However the summary page "Accounts" title still links to it, which just reloads the summary page:

[image: Accounts Summary Title link]

The "view more" link takes me correctly through to Stack Exchange page as indicated by the icon.

I'm currently seeing `rev 2012.4.5.2106` in the bottom right here on Meta and LEGO Answers.

Comment: Noo - I miss it already!

Comment: @Rory - Indeed, I too, clearly I use it, as I noticed it was broken ;)

Comment: Hmm...I see it.. And I use it quite a bit as well :/

Comment: Apparently, that tab is now [superceded by the SE network profile](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/929027#929027), i.e. http://stackexchange.com/users/15574/zhaph-ben-duguid?tab=accounts. One less page to keep in sync across profiles I suppose.

Comment: @ShawnChin - that's actually pulled totally from APIv2 on either side, so no sync work above the total aggregation anyway...this is to make room for another long-standing request, stay tuned.

Comment: @ShawnChin - Yep, as you can see from the last part of my Question, I could see it had moved to the main Stack Exchange site, I was just pointing out the broken link ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a build rolling out now, that header will link directly to your stackexchange.com accounts page.  We'll get with Jin and get a visual indicator on there that it takes you away from the current site (as the view more link does), since that's not the behavior of the other profile panels.

Also, we'll now redirect any old `?tab=accounts` links on your profile accordingly so those aren't 404s.

Comment: Cheers Nick, seems to have deployed nicely here on meta and LEGO Answers with `rev 2012.4.5.2108`